# terraform) how to stop instance after running script(inline)?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, terraform

I create 30 instance to run crawl script, and want to stop aws instances after complete running this command, `python3 aws_crawl.py`, but I cannot find how to stop current aws instance by command line.

Please see my `main.tf` code below:

```sh
resource "aws_instance" "crawl_worker" {
  ami             = "${var.ami_id}"
  instance_type   = "t3a.nano"
  security_groups = ["${var.aws_security_group}"]
  key_name = "secret"
  count = 10
  tags =  {
    Name = "crawl_worker_${count.index}"
  }

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = "${self.public_ip}"
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("~/secret.pem")}"
    timeout = "50m"
  }


   provisioner "remote-exec" {
                            inline = [
                            "python3 aws_crawl.py"
                            ]
                           }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good use of Terraform. You need something else to help orchestrate here. For your use case I'd suggest using something like Glue or Batch here instead. Or some other data orchestration framework.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Got it, Thanks~!